# Tool to automatically format python code?

Tags: python, vim

So when writing C/C++, I get to use the wonderful Clangformat tool, allowing me to write a loooong line and hit a keyboard shortcut to easily and elegantly format my line according to a sane style guide.

Is there an equivalent tool for python? Bonus points if it has a vim plugin.

Comment: vim-autoformat integrates autopep8 into vim: https://github.com/Chiel92/vim-autoformat

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**autopep8**:

- https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autopep8/

> A tool that automatically formats Python code to conform to the PEP 8 style guide

To use:

```
pip install --upgrade autopep8
autopep8 --in-place --aggressive --aggressive <filename>
```